# Kotlin: If HashMap does not contain a certain value, then create key

Tags: kotlin

I have the following HashMap:

```
val myHashMap: HashMap<key, ValueClass>
```

where:

```
data class ValueClass(
    var a: Long = 0,
    var b: Long = 0
)
```

I'd like to use the myHashMap as follows: if myHashMap, does not contain the key x, create a new ValueClass and insert it into myHashMap, then myHashMap[x].a = newValue

what is the cleanest way to do so?
In Java I would have had:

```
    if(!myHashMap.containsKey("x"))
    {
        map.put("x",new ValueClass());
    }
    map.get("x").a=newValue;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [MutableMap#getOrPut](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-or-put.html)

```
myMap.getOrPut("key") { "default_value" }
```

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative:

```
val foo = map["x"] ?: ValueClass().also { map["x"] = it }

foo.x = newValue
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `run()` to create the value if it doesn't exist.

```
val foo = map["x"] ?: run {
    val bar = ValueClass()
    map["x"] = bar
    bar
}

foo.x = newValue
```

This will fetch `map.get("x")` when present, otherwise it will evaluate the `run` block. The block creates your new instance, puts it in the map, and "returns" the new instance.

Therefore, `foo` is always non-null, and then you can update it.